# Doing a Spy in a Mocha (Ruby) test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, ruby-mocha

My team uses [Mocha](https://github.com/freerange/mocha) for unit testing in Ruby. I'd like to use Mocha to add a "spy" on a method.  That is, I'd like to write a unit test using Mocha that verifies that the code under test calls a particular method on another class, without overriding the implementation of that method.

Is that possible? If so, how can it be done?

I've tried using Mocha's [`expects`](http://gofreerange.com/mocha/docs/Mocha/Mock.html#expects-instance_method), like:

```
MyModule::MyClass.expects(:my_method)
```

However, that overrides the implementation of `my_method`. In my particular situation, I need to both verify that `my_method` was called, and to have the actual implementation of the method execute during the test.

Comment: i could only found the older Q&A, but mocha seems to lack the functionality of rspec's `#and_call_original`